# Code runs in parallel in LinqPad, but not in Console App...why?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, linqpad

I'm needing to make a series of calls to a single web service for different date ranges, and generate a concatenated result set.  I'd like to make the calls in parallel to speed up the process, though I have limited experience in this area.

I tried several techniques, but based on the execution time, my code calls continue to run in sequence when I run them in a Visul Studio console app.  By that I mean if a call for a one month date range takes 15 seconds, then three of those one month calls, supposedly running in parallel, is taking 45 seconds.

But here's the part that really surprised me: I started running the exact same code in LinqPad for easier debugging.  Lo and behold, in LinqPad the same code does run in parallel!  Calling for 3 months takes about 15 seconds total!

Now I'm scratching my head as to how this could be.  I've tried copying the LinqPad version to a new conole project (to doublecheck that everything really is the same in both versions), but it doesn't change the behavior.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.  I'm not sure which code is relevant to the issue, but I've included a slightly simplified version of the web service calling class below:

```
class Importer
{
    public List<FuncDetails> GetAllData(DateRange[] intervals)
    {
        Task<List<PropFuncsType>>[] tasks = intervals
            .ToList()
            .Select(interval => GetDataForIntervalAsync(interval.StartDate, interval.EndDate))
            .ToArray();

        var result = new List<ResultDataTable>();
        Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, results => { foreach (var output in results) { result.AddRange(output.Result); } })
        .Wait();

        return result.SelectMany(x => x.ResultDataRow).ToList();

    }

    async static private Task<List<ResultDataTable>> GetDataForIntervalAsync(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        var service = new ServiceClient();

        var result = await service.getDataAsync(new ServiceRequest()
            {
                startDate = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", startDate),
                endDate = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", endDate)
            }
        );

        return result.ServiceResponse.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`?

Comment: That's it!  `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` is effectively a global and the LinqPad host must have set it to a high value outside my code.  I've been banging my head on this for two days.  Please make your comment an answer so I can give you proper credit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to `int.MaxValue` when your console app starts up. This is a common-but-subtle cause of HTTP throttling on .NET.

(Presumably, LINQPad already does something similar).

Comment: Increasing the value from the default (2) was exactly the answer, though I did initially find setting it to a value much beyond 24 (in my case) inadvertently led to a denial-of-service attack on my own web service provider. :-) With great power comes great responsibility, and I think that limitation is probably better managed explicitly in my calling code. Cheers.

Comment: I have a code which took ~3s in LINQPad and ~60s in Console app. I tried to set `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;` inside my console app, but doesn't work. any idea?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani: You should post the code as a separate question.